# split sql string on ',' and '|'

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, list, foreach

My goal is to convert the sql string

```
 'element1|value,element2|value2,element3|value3'
```

into

```
'<element1>value</element1>
<element2>value2</element1>
<element3>value3</element1>'
```

My thoughts are

```
declare @test as varchar(max) = 'element1|value1,element2|value2,element3|value3'

SELECT CHARINDEX(',',@test)

SELECT SUBSTRING(@test,0,CHARINDEX(',',@test))
```

The problem I am having is i am not very familar with sql, is there a list feature or something I can use to group this into 3 chunks, then dissect each chunk?

Comment: Does it have to be done in SQL?  SQL not designed for splitting strings.  Is there another layer that could do the parsing?

Comment: @DStanley you have no idea how much I wish this was possible somewhere else

Comment: Is your desired output multiple rows per input row like your sample?

Comment: @GoatCO my desired output is any working object. a string with all the info, a table with 2 columns, i can consume anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse strings using `XML` functionality:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT testString = 'element1|value,element2|value2,element3|value3'
              UNION  SELECT 'test,1,2,3'
              )
     ,SplitString AS (SELECT testString,
                             CONVERT(XML,'<String><Section>'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(testString ,'|',','),',', '</Section><Section>') + '</Section></String>') AS xmlString
                      FROM cte
                      )    
 SELECT xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[1]','varchar(100)') AS Col1
       ,xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[2]','varchar(100)') AS Col2
       ,xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[3]','varchar(100)') AS Col3
       ,xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[4]','varchar(100)') AS Col4
 FROM SplitString
```

Here I've just changed your `|` to `,` and done all the splitting in one fell swoop, but if it's not all even pairs you could do this in two steps, first splitting on `|` then on `,`.

You could also look into `PARSENAME()` but it's limited to 4 sections, or you could create a `PARSE` function, like:

```
/********************************************************************************************
        Create Parse Function
********************************************************************************************/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_PARSE(@chunk VARCHAR(4000), @delimiter CHAR(1), @index INT )
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @curIndex INT = 0,
        @pos INT = 1,
        @prevPos INT = 0,
        @result VARCHAR(1000)
    WHILE @pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @pos =  CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @chunk, @prevPos);
        IF(@pos > 0)
        BEGIN -- Characters between position and previous position
            SET @result = SUBSTRING(@chunk, @prevPos, @pos-@prevPos)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN -- Last Delim
            SET @result = SUBSTRING(@chunk, @prevPos, LEN(@chunk))
        END
        IF(@index = @curIndex)
        BEGIN
            RETURN @result
        END
        SET @prevPos = @pos + 1
        SET @curIndex = @curIndex + 1;
    END
    RETURN '' -- Else Empty
END
```

Which is then called simply:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT testString = 'element1|value,element2|value2,element3|value3'
              UNION  SELECT 'test,1,2,3'
              )
 SELECT  dbo.FN_PARSE(testString ,'|', 0) AS Col1
        ,dbo.FN_PARSE(testString ,'|', 1) AS Col2
        ...
 FROM cte
```

Note the indexing for the section starts at `0` in the above function.

I'm keen on the `XML` version presently, but haven't done much comparison testing.

Comment: I really like this. Also, changing the end SELECT to just a SELECT xmlString.query('/') returns as xml document, which is awesome. Im looking now at combining to look like xml document under one root node with name/value pairs

Answer (score 0):

Just to have options :-), if the end goal is to transform the input string into XML, you can use a Regular Expression Replace to do this and it wouldn't be constrained to any number of elements:

```sql
DECLARE @Sample NVARCHAR(500),
        @ElementBasedXML NVARCHAR(500),
        @AttributeBasedXML NVARCHAR(500);

SELECT @Sample = N'element1|value,element2|value2,element3|value3',
       @ElementBasedXML = N'<$2>$3</$2>' + NCHAR(10),
       @AttributeBasedXML = N'<row $2="$3" />' + NCHAR(10);

SELECT SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(@Sample, N'(([^|,]+)\|([^|,]+)),?', @ElementBasedXML,
                            -1, 1, Null) AS [ElementBased],
       SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(@Sample, N'(([^|,]+)\|([^|,]+)),?', @AttributeBasedXML,
                            -1, 1, Null) AS [AttributeBased];
```

Returns:

```
ElementBased
------------
<element1>value</element1>
<element2>value2</element2>
<element3>value3</element3>

AttributeBased
--------------
<row element1="value" />
<row element2="value2" />
<row element3="value3" />
```

Or, you can split the string on the commas inside a CTE (giving an unlimited number of Key-Value pairs separated by pipe symbols) and then splitting those pairs on their single delimiter:

```sql
DECLARE @Sample2 NVARCHAR(500);

SELECT @Sample = N'element1|value,element2|value2,element3|value3';

;WITH kvpairs AS
(
  SELECT split.SplitVal,
         CHARINDEX(N'|', split.SplitVal) AS [PipeLocation],
         LEN(split.SplitVal) AS [PairLength]
  FROM   SQL#.String_Split4k(@Sample2, N',', 1) split
), pieces AS
(
  SELECT LEFT(kvpairs.SplitVal, (kvpairs.PipeLocation - 1)) AS [Key],
         RIGHT(kvpairs.SplitVal, (kvpairs.PairLength - kvpairs.PipeLocation))
               AS [Value]
  FROM   kvpairs
)
SELECT  CONVERT(XML, N'<' + pieces.[Key] + N'>'
                + pieces.[Value] 
                + N'</' + pieces.[Key] + N'>')
FROM   pieces
FOR XML PATH('');
```

Please note:

- Both examples make use of the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library, which is a collection of SQLCLR functions and procs (which I wrote, but the functions shown here are in the Free version).
- The RegEx method is fine as is for use in a SELECT statement against a table, passing in a column as the expression to be evaluated. The Split/CTE method would need to be placed into a function (an inline TVF) in order to be used in a query via `CROSS APPLY`.
- The second example, doing the split, doesn't have to use SQLCLR; it can use a pure T-SQL splitter using an inline tally table or XML.

Comment: while I have no issues with either one, unfortunatly SQL# library is not available to me.

Comment: @CalvinSmith No SQLCLR policy? Either way, just thought I would mention the possibility. The second example, doing the split, is still an option since you can use a pure T-SQL splitter using an inline tally table or XML. And so you would still not be limited by the number of elements. Option #2 doesn't have to use SQLCLR.